# Table-cells with float or inline-block elements mess up with contents of other table-cells

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I spent all night trying to understand this.

When I'm styling the contents of a div in my webpage, it interferes with the contents of other divs that are neither the parent nor child divs. The content of unrelated divs shouldn't be independent? Despite this I've tried to understand and solve my particular problem, but without any luck. More than a solution, I need an explanation.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gQ3U2/

and the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content {
    display: table;
}

#columnleft {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    display: table-cell;
}

#columncenter {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    display: table-cell;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="columnleft">
        <div class="menu">
            this menu
            <br/>
            takes
            <br/>
            some space
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="columncenter">
        this should be on top
        <br/>
        but only appears here if:
        <br/>
        a) menu has display: inline-block or
        <br/>
        b) menu has float: right
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

a) I think this is a problem with table-cells layout because in float layout it doesn't happen. Is this a limitation of display:table?

b) In case of float:right I've found that a 
 after the menu makes the problem disapear. Why?

c) clear:both after the menu doesn't work

d) I'm not interested in nobody-understands-why-hacks nor in correcting the changes the menu makes in the other div "manually" nor choosing another root that doesn't have this problem. I want to be able to align the menu to the right using float, fit divs to contents using inline-block and keep using table cells, everything, if possible, without positioning.

Thanks beforehand,
Jose

Comment: Add "vertical-align: top;" to #columncenter

Comment: that is correcting the side-effect. if I don't put float:right or inline-block the content flows from top. Why I need vertical-align in the first place? maybe here the side-effect is easly resolved but in other situations the same behavior might be impossible to correct

Answer (score 1):

Is there a concrete reason to use `display: table`?

There isn't really a need to use `display:table` for most layout options. A good solution is often just to use floats.

As an example:

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ3U2/1/)

CSS

```
html, body, #content {
    height: 100%;
}
#columnleft {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
#columncenter {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: well, thats avoiding the problem and not explaining it (which I am considering but it's not the subject of this question)

Comment: Fair enough. This seems like a pointless thing to worry about... If you are using `display:table` to arrange you column on the left, why are you floating your menu inside it? There are lots of CSS quirks :)

Comment: Thanks :) about your previous comments: 1) theoretically we shouldn't use floats to layout, that an abuse and browser support nowardays don't make that abuse necessary. 2) the float or inline-block in the menu is to make its width fit to its content (and then align to the right). How else could I make a menu a) right aligned in the parent div b) left aligned inside content ? cheers

Answer (score 0):

Defaut `vertical-align` of `<td>` or `table-cell` displayed elements needs to be reset to top if you want them behave like regular flow content:

```
#content {
    display: table;
}

#columnleft {

    display: table-cell;  
    vertical-align:top;
}
#columnleft {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

#columncenter {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ3U2/2/)**

Comment: same as above (that is correcting the side-effect. if I don't put float:right or inline-block the content flows from top. Why I need vertical-align in the first place? maybe here the side-effect is easly resolved but in other situations the same behavior might be impossible to correct)

Comment: You need to reset vertical-align to any value you wish. It is typical behavior of table-cells/td/th elements. In no case vertical-align won't be applied to theses, unless taken of the flow via float or absolute/fixed position . :)

Comment: Hi, what is stange is having the vertical alignment behavior in the center div change according to what I do inside the left div. In doesn't make much sense. But, thanks for your input :)